# project struct to a array of bytes in c

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I have array of chars:

```
char buffer[1024];
```

The array in fact contains chain of structures in sequence.

```
struct MyStruct {
    char name[4];
    int num1;
    int num2; 
}
```

I want to loop through the array:

```
MyStruct *p;
for(int i = 0;i < sizeof(buffer);i += sizeof(MyStruct))
{
    // how can I point p to some place in buffer here?    
}
```

I want to point `p` to start of `buffer`, the to `buffer + 12` etc.

Comment: You are about to cross a thin red line here called *strict aliasing*...

Comment: Such buffers are typically from marshalling/serialisation. Learn about that subject and do it the correct way member-wise. First define the format of the data in the buffer so that it does not rely on implementation-specific details.

Answer (score 3):

One issue to consider is that the char buffer might not be properly aligned for a struct (and, in this case, its int members `num1` and `num2`). Depending on the platform and implementation, a 4-byte, 8-byte or 16-byte alignment might be required. For that reason, one alternative is to declare the buffer in terms of `MyStruct` initially and then access it via a char pointer:

```
MyStruct buffer[1024 / sizeof(MyStruct)];
char * cp = (char *) buffer;
// fill the buffer via cp
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i)
{
    // do stuff with buffer[i]
}
```

If that approach is not possible, the buffer needs to be copied to another buffer with safe alignment; For example:

```
size_t n = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(MyStruct);
MyStruct * p = (MyStruct *) malloc(n * sizeof(MyStruct));
if (!p) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
memcpy(p, buffer, n * sizeof(MyStruct));  // copy buffer to p
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    // do stuff with p[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first note that you are assuming that this will work. That there is no padding between the elements of the struct. Having said that do this:

```
MyStruct *s = (MyStruct*)(buffer + i)
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what I need.

Comment: There is a bunch of other things one has to assume... Like the alignment. Not my DV, though, if you are wondering..

Answer (score 0):

You let `p` point to the first struct in the buffer, then increment it on each iteration:

```
MyStruct *p= (struct MyStruct *) buffer;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i += sizeof(MyStruct), p++)
{
    // your code 
}
```

...and yes, this assumes the structs are contiguous in memory, with no padding in between.